# Find a sub audio in the long audio

Tags: python, ruby, audio, wav

I am trying to solve a problem: find a sub audio in the long audio.

Let assume that I have 500 audio files (wav files). All these files contain three or more letters, read by lecturer, with ~1s silence, all the letters are always the same but combinations are different. For example `ABCD`, `BCA`, `DAB` etc.

I want to write a script which gives me a code read by the person.

I have loaded one audio in the audacity program and copy one audio letter, past and save to another file called a.wav. This one audio letter read by lecturer is a sub audio for me.

[image]

I want to check by the program if the loaded long audio contains a letter from sub audio like `a.wav`, `b.wav`, `c.wav`.

```
# ruby
long_audio = MyAudio.new "abcd.wav"
if (position = long_audio.index('a.wav')).present?
   puts "Letter A is on the position #{position}"
end
```

Is it possible to do programmatically?

Similar method for strings in ruby can return a position of substring like `"ABC".index("B")`. I want the same for audios. How to do it?

Comment: `.index` would only work if the samples of spoken letters were cut & paste in an audio editor. If the audio is (as seems likely) just a recording of clearly spoken letters, then the match cannot be done this way, the data for "A" will be quite different bytes each time. You should be using a statistical or machine-learning match technique.

Comment: Probably you could work with a simple statistical technique (e.g. least difference) if you extracted a "feature vector" from each spoken  letter. That will involve identifying each spoken section of the input, and extracting features. Search for "audio feature extraction" or similar - this is too broad a topic for a simple answer on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @NeilSlater thanks for your comments. I see that's not so easy, I have been working on this for last 2 weeks. Like you mentioned, I will try to do it with some simple techniques e.g. statistical. I'm thinking about extract silence moments and create a vector of every spoken letter.

Comment: @LukaszSliwa did you find a way?